# value javascript function and dom

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function  one window and takes the value and passes it on dom script and writes the output to the screen on `<div>` or `<p>` or `<a>` and all work well.

My point is change the dom element and put the value on one text input.
I try to call my input id on the function and write the value with innerHTML,but nor work well.

I not call the function on the input elements but on other dom elements.

this is the code

```
 var vect = [];

function close(val) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("output");     
  elem.innerHTML = "";
  vect.length = 0;
  for (var i in val.multiple) {
    var d = val.multiple[i];
    if (c) {
      elem.innerHTML += c.print("%A, %Y %B %d");         
      vect[vect.length] = c;
    }
  }
  val.hide();
  return true;
}
```

thanks all

Comment: never append to the `.innerHTML` in a loop like that - append the desired values to a string and then just set the `.innerHTML` just once after the loop.

Comment: What is `c` supposed to be?

Comment: Why `vect.length = 0;` when `[].length` is `0` already so not needed and why `vect[vect.length] = c;` instead of `vect.push(c)`?

Comment: sorry        right  code is        var c= val.multiple[i];   i not think gillesc is important your...is only the vector

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value of an `input` element, you need to use `value`, not `innerHTML`. Should be :

```
elem.value += c.print("%A, %Y %B %d");
```